# jQuery/Javascript - Run function before (document).ready for the purpose of loading an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I am trying to get the dimensions of an image in order to resize (or size) a canvas of it's length with twice the width. (So, for a 400x800 image I want a 800x800 canvas). What I'm trying to do right now is load the image twice, once to determine it's size and another time to display it. My HTML w/ Javascript/JQuery looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Canvas from scratch</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jcanvas.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1100" height="500">
        </canvas>
    <script>

        $("<img />").attr("src", "test1image.jpg").load(function() {
            /* This is where I'd like to load the image to get its dimensions */
        });

        $(document).ready(
                function() {


                    var imgWidth, imgHeight;
                    var imageData; 

                    var image = new Image();
                    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

                    $(image).load(function() {
                        /* This is where the image is loaded and 
                           inserted into the canvas */
                        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
                    });
                    image.src = "test1image.jpg"; 

                    imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0,
                            image.width,
                            );

                    /* This is just part of the image manipulation, 
                       bland right now */
                    var newImgData = ctx.createImageData(imageData.width,
                            imageData.height);
                    for ( var i = 0; i < newImgData.data.length; i += 4) {
                        newImgData.data[i + 0] = 255;
                        newImgData.data[i + 1] = 0; 
                        newImgData.data[i + 2] = 0; 
                        newImgData.data[i + 3] = 255;       
                    }
                    ctx.putImageData(newImgData, imageData.width, 0);

                });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

One thing I've kept trying but noticed is not working is trying to place the function before (document).ready, but if the (document).ready call always comes first. I can't seem to get the image to load without the canvas already being created (because it is in the (document).ready call). Can anyone explain what's going on?

Thanks.

Edit_1: I just tried adding

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
            $("<img />").attr("src", "test1image.jpg").load(function() {
                imgWidth = this.width;
            });
        });
```

to the top of the script, but imgWidth is being declared as undefined in (document).ready.

Edit_2: So, that actually worked really well blgt. Here's the new code, and it's 100% functional. The new canvas size is exactly what I wanted, based on the image dimensions and it all works... only thing I'm thinking is that there might be one too many nested functions but I'll try to work that out on my own.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Canvas from scratch</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jcanvas.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1100" height="500">
        </canvas>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(
                function() {
                    $("<img>").attr("src", "test1image.jpg").on('load', function() {
                        var imgWidth, imgHeight;
                        var imageData; 
                        var image = new Image();
                        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                        ctx.canvas.width = this.width * 2;
                        ctx.canvas.height = this.height; 
                        $(image).on("load", function() {
                            /* This is where the image is loaded and 
                               inserted into the canvas */
                            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

                        });
                        image.src = "test1image.jpg"; 

                        imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0,
                                this.width,
                                this.height);

                        /* This is just part of the image manipulation, 
                           bland right now */
                        var newImgData = ctx.createImageData(imageData.width,
                                imageData.height);
                        for ( var i = 0; i < newImgData.data.length; i += 4) {
                            newImgData.data[i + 0] = 255;
                            newImgData.data[i + 1] = 0; 
                            newImgData.data[i + 2] = 0; 
                            newImgData.data[i + 3] = 255;       
                        }
                        ctx.putImageData(newImgData, imageData.width, 0);
                 });
                });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I doubt that the image load callback would trigger before DOM ready. The image node is going to be loaded before the actual image and its dimensions. What you want to do is do your image work on image load not DOM ready.

Comment: I've tried forcing it on [image].onload, but it still falls behind the document ready. I'll post my attempt in an edit though just in case I'm being stupid.

Comment: That was my point it will always fall behind document ready. Because document structure is loaded before content. `<img>` tag is loaded before the real image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This syntax: `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) is deprecated, use `.on('load'...` instead. Also, this won't delay execution of the function in `.ready`. Is there a reason you can't do the simple, stupid thing and just put a callback to that function inside the `.on('load', handler)` handler instead?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $("<img>").attr("src", "test1image.jpg").on('load', function() {
                // do stuff with dimensions

                var imgWidth, imgHeight;
                var imageData; 
                // ... etc.

         });
});
```

Comment: So, the simple, stupid thing worked really well. Not exactly sure why, but it's all up and running now. Thanks for the help- I'm gonna try and figure this all out before moving forward.

Comment: [It usually does, especially so for proto-versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to shoehorn a synchronous sequence onto an asynchronous model, and basically you just don't want to do this.

The document ready event is *supposed* to fire before other assets have been loaded: http://api.jquery.com/ready/ - note it mentions exactly the case you're asking about.

> In cases where code relies on loaded assets (for example, if the dimensions of an image are required), the code should be placed in a handler for the load event instead.

So you should be able to just change your code to use `document.load()` instead of `document.ready()` but this will then wait until *all* assets are loaded. If you only want to wait for that specific image to load, you should move the code from `document.ready` to the image's `load` event.

EDIT:

Your new code basically does the last option - moves the code into the image's load event, which is probably the best overall as it allows your code to run as soon as the particular image is ready. You can potentially make it happen sooner by pre-loading the image in an inline script before loading your JS libraries etc. which would allow the image to start downloading in parallel to other assets, rather than waiting for the document ready event to start the image loading.

Comment: Huh, that also sounds like a solution. I'm not entirely sure why the current code is running without errors right now, but I'm definitely going to have to go through it all a few times. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @A4Treok Your new code basically does the last option - moves the code into the image's `load` event, which is probably the best overall as it allows your code to run as soon as the particular image is ready. You can potentially make it happen sooner by pre-loading the image in an inline script before loading your JS libraries etc. which would allow the image to start downloading in parallel to other assets, rather than waiting for the dom ready event to start the image loading.

Comment: Ah, OK. I will do that in the final version for sure because I'll be dealing with a semi-large image, and thanks for the explanation.